# How to print pdf in chrome but make text inside pdf unselectable?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdf-generation, printthis

I need to download the pdf of html page for which i have used chrome builtin, printing feature to save as pdf. However, I don't want my users to be able to simply copy paste the text, No matter if they use image ocr to extract text, they should not be able to easily copy text, how to make this possible?

Comment: *"No matter if they use image ocr to extract text, they should not be able to easily copy text"* - how do you expect to prevent OCR? (Short of making the text barely legible and so increasing the ocr error rate beyond something usable; but who would want to read such a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A easy / fast solution is to use 'html2canvas' ([link to website](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)). You just would have to add the parameter `canvas` with the value `true` to the `printThis` config-parameter, so that it works.

The code would look like this:

```js
   html2canvas(document.querySelector("#page")).then(canvas => {
       $(canvas).printThis({ canvas: true })
   });
```

Where the html - Element with the `id`of `#page` contains the html you want to print/convert to pdf. With other words, it is the same element, on which you would call the `printThis` function.

Here a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vwfb20sp/

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ =>
     html2canvas(document.querySelector('#page'))
     .then(canvas => {
         document.body.appendChild(canvas)
         $('#page').printThis({ 
                canvas: true 
         })
     })
);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/1.4.1/html2canvas.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/printThis/1.15.0/printThis.min.js">
</script> 
<body >
    <div id ="page">
        test
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/89/Amber_mountain_rock_thrush_%28Monticola_sharpei_erythronotus%29_male_2.jpg/1200px-Amber_mountain_rock_thrush_%28Monticola_sharpei_erythronotus%29_male_2.jpg" alt="Amber mountain rock thrush (Monticola sharpei erythronotus) male 2.jpg" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I have corss domain images to be served in webpage, where html2canvas fails.

Comment: If you cannot "adapt" the servers, to allow cors calls  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image), than as far as I know the only way would, be to generate the pdf on the Server side. What to do there would depend on which programming language and libraries are available.

Comment: Hi winner_joiner, Can you jsfiddle a small code which uses cross domain image and is recognised by canvas? I am new to all this and your help will greatly appreciated.

Comment: @FutekoTV I updated the answer with a jsfiddle, BUT if you get an error because of cross-domain- issues it ois because, the server that is providing the images, is not sending the needed `HTTP Headers`, without changing this it won't work. If you cant change it, you will need code this serverside, this means not javascript, and much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

There is generally no way to dictate how your server clients should behave. so using the example above IF I wish to change the server text or image outputs for my accessibility, such as Reading or text preferences, I can use the browser control of a server offerings like this:-

[image]

HTTPS is dis(re)position of hyper text from one ownership to another, The server may pr-offer objects but the client may refuse images (or other content like adverts) and adapt the server offerings to their own tastes.

When using browser for pdf **the editor is the clients owned server**

[image]